# groupby column while showing other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
name | $ | letter
adam, 34,  c
beny, 45,  e
adam, 55,  a
beny, 87,  t
```

**I'd like to extract the max $ donated by each name, with the respective letter.**
So for Adam, I would get: adam,55,a.

If I use:

```
df.groupby('name')[['$']].max()
```

that doesn't give me the respective letter.

If I use:

```
df.groupby('name')[['$','letter']].max()
```

I get the max $ and the highest letter in the alphabet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indexes of max values and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.groupby('name')['$'].idxmax())
name
adam    2
beny    3
Name: $, dtype: int64

df = df.loc[df.groupby('name')['$'].idxmax()]
print (df)
   name   $ letter
2  adam  55      a
3  beny  87      t
```

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first and then use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('$').groupby('name', as_index=False).last()
print (df)
   name   $ letter
0  adam  55      a
1  beny  87      t
```

Difference in solutions is `idxmax` let original indexes, `last` reset them.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.